# Getline function

Tags: c, io

The following is my attempt at writing a `getline()` function that makes it a bit easier to work with. I suppose an easier way would be to use `fgets`, but hopefully the following is good enough for some feedback:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TITLE_MAX 50

void mygets(char buffer[], size_t limit)
{
    // first non-space char until newline or EOF, 
    // eating any extra chars in buffer
    // will add \0 at the end, so will get up to N-1 chars

    int c, idx=0;
    bool started=false;
    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (!started && isspace(c));
        if (idx < limit-1) {
            started = true;
            buffer[idx++] = c;
        }
    }
    buffer[idx] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char tbuffer[TITLE_MAX];
    while (true) 
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the film (empty line to stop)\n");
        mygets(tbuffer, TITLE_MAX);
        if (*tbuffer=='\0') break;
        printf("The title is: %s\n", tbuffer);
    }
}
```

Working example [on onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/rJufsGVQd)

How does it look? How could it be improved? Additionally, how are comments usually done in C code? It is usually within the function braces? Before the function? etc.

Comment: David542,  how do you want to distinguish between end-of-file and reading only `"\n"`?

Comment: What is the goal with code like `if (!started && isspace(c));`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica to skip leading whitespace (`\s` being used to mean space): `\s\s\s Hello, chux` --> `Hello, chux`. But it looks like that's bad code and there's an error within it.

Comment: David542 Why skip all leading white-space and not symmetrically all trailing white-space (aside from 1 `'\n'`) as with `"  ABC  \n"`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica no reason, I suppose doing both would be better as you suggest.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica hm to be honest I hadn't thought about that. Perhaps the function can return a code, such as `NULL` if nothing was read or the size of the read data (or maybe just 0 if empty or 1 if non-empty). What is the suggested way to usually do this?

Answer (score 2):

- You should be getting a warning (at least I do):

  ```
  warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]
    if (!started && isspace(c));
                               ^
  ```

  This line does absolutely nothing. Judging from the comment, you probably meant

  ```
    if (!started && isspace(c))
        continue;
  ```
- The loop looks overcomplicated. Its logic cries to be split into two independent actions: `skip_initial_spaces` and `actually_read_data`, performed sequentially (again, assuming that I read the comment correctly).

  Factoring them out into the functions of their own will also make your code comply with a single responsibility principle.
- I strongly advise against `void` functions. Do not discard the information you have already computed; it is very likely the caller will need it. In this case, returning `idx` will spare the caller an additional call to `strlen`.

EDIT. On splitting up the functionality, something along these lines:

```
int skip_leading_whitespaces()
{
    int c;
    while (((c = getchar()) != EOF) && isspace(c)) {
    }
    return c;
}

int actually_read_data(int c, char buffer[], size_t limit)
{
    int idx = 0;
    while ((c != EOF) && (c != '\n')) {
        buffer[idx++] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }
    buffer[idx] = 0;
    return idx;
}

int mygets(char buffer[], size_t limit)
{   
    int c = skip_leading_whitespaces();
    return actually_read_data(c, buffer[], limit);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. Could you describe how it might be split up into `skip_initial_spaces` and `actually_read_data` in a couple lines of code or so?

Comment: @David542 see edit.

Comment: OP's code only reads up to 1 line.  This code may read  multiple lines with `skip_leading_whitespaces()`.

Comment: `actually_read_data()` does not  use `limit`.  As you say " something along these lines:".

Answer (score 0):

**Incorrect code to skip leading white space**

**Asymmetrically attempts to skip leading  white-spaces but not all trailing ones**

**Mixed types**

Rather than `size_t limit, int idx`.  Use the same type.  Recommend `size_t`

**Edge cases behavior woe**

`idx < limit-1` is like `idx < SIZE_MAX` when `limit == 0`.  Better as `idx + 1 < limit`.

**No return**

No clear what to distinguish end-of-file from reading `"\n"`.

---

I'd set aside the skip leading white-space goal for now.

Comment: thanks. Would you want to post an updated version of the code with how it can be improved?

Comment: @David542 Still waiting on [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256896/getline-function/257003?noredirect=1#comment507533_256896).